# Is it possible to use 3.3v pin as usual GPIO for general purposes?

Tags: gpio, power

Need 6 pins one after another, but can't imagine where I can get them. Any ideas?

Comment: This is not how it works. The 3V3 pins are not *General Purpose*, they are hard wired to the 3V3 rail. There are other ways to increase the number of available GPIO "pins", i.e. using [shift registers](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=gpio+shift+register) or [port expanders](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=gpio+port+expander)... but we need some more detailled requirements - especially the bandwidth. That is the rate of data transfer - say this number of GPIO pins (think bits) toggled at this frequency. You can trade one for the other.

Comment: This is a good one on I2C port expanders https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/4749/19949 or https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/10297/19949

Comment: I assume you've looked at the [GPIO documentation published by The Organization](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/gpio/), and know there aren't 6 adjacent GPIO pins. I'm pretty thick, so I can't imagine why that's a requirement, but if you care to explain what you're trying to accomplish, we might be able to offer something beyond the obvious.