# Connecting several (roughly 100) Buttons to the PI (USB?)

Tags: gpio, python-3, switches

I havent found anything, but iam sure there is already info on the topic. So even just a link would be helpful for me.

I want to build a Jukebox. So pretty simple. Around 30 Buttons, if Button is pushed add song to queue. Thats it more or less.

Since Iam a total newbee to pi and python:

How would I add several buttons to the pi?
And what would the code roughly look like?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: To add a little more Info, I would need around 100 buttons. As far as I could google this means Iam gonna ned several GPIO extensions(?).
How could I get and work with so many signals? The command would be simple for each one.

Maybe USB would be a better option then GPIO for this amount? Iam not to keen on buying 8 extensions boards for 20€ each.

Maybe thing of it as a DIY piano ^^

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure how much research you've tried but there was a similar question asked a few days ago (for the hardware side): https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/96259/93934

Comment: Thanks @RogerJones. Its definitly the right direction but I would be more intrested in setting up the keys myself since I dont know yet how much I will use or possibly add more over time. This off ocurse depends on how complex it will be do it myself :)

Comment: There are thousands of tutorials for connecting buttons to the Raspberry Pi on the www.  You need to look through them and choose one.  If you then have a problem we may be able to help if you ask a detailed question.

Comment: @joan Yeah its true there are a lot of tutorials but I couldnt find one explaning how to connect more switches(buttons then there are GPIO Pins. I already understand that I may need an extension board. But how would i realize the software to such a thing?
If you know of any tutorial thats explains this or is similar please tell me :D

Answer (score 3):

You could simply wire the buttons up as a matrix, your usecase already describes the buttons being placed in a grid pattern. If you wire all the button pins vertically and horizontally you can form a matrix, with the 28 GPIO pins avalible on all Pi models but the first edition. You should be able to theoretically run 14^2 buttons or aprox 196 buttons.

The way this would be run is, you would have an infinite loop that would constantly power 1 column at a time, then while that column was powered if any of your row pins recieved power you would know that a button was depressed and you would know the (x,y) coordinates of said depressed button. You can read more about the concept [here](https://www.baldengineer.com/arduino-keyboard-matrix-tutorial.html).